# How to disable auto scrolling for Bootstrap carousel?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have tried multiple changes including removing the `data-bs-ride="carousel"` to stop the carousel from auto scrolling but it is still happening once the `$("#mycarousel").carousel('next');` triggers.

Here's my carousel:

```
<div id="mycarousel" data-bs-interval="false" class="carousel slide">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img src="..."></img>
            <audio id="" src="..."></audio>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="..."></img>
            <audio id=""></audio>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is the script that I'm using to control it:

```
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $("#mycarousel").carousel('next');
        $("#mycarousel").on('slid.bs.carousel', function () {
            $slide = $('div.active');
            var $audioInSlide = $slide.find('audio')[0];
            if($audioInSlide.hasAttribute("src")){
                var $audio = $audioInSlide;
                audio.play();
                $('#mycarousel').carousel('pause');
            } else {
                setInterval(function() {
                    $("#mycarousel").carousel('next');
                }, 5000);
            }
        })     
    })
</script>
```

The code is intended to play audio for slide with embedding audio and slide the others if audio not existing.

Adding and removing data-bs-ride="carousel" based on the instruction here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/carousel/